# Chromecast on public wi-fi; control over internet

Tags: vpn, chromecast

I'm interested in setting up a Chromecast dongle for a relative in the hospital.  Can the Chromecast be set up on a VPN, and then be controlled remotely by a phone or Chrome browser on that VPN?

We have no control over port forwarding, of course, but would ask about the facility's data use policy, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

This would require some sort of site-to-site VPN.  Since there is no VPN software that runs on the Chromecast you'd have to create a wifi network that is connected to the VPN.  There are several services that offer this such as neorouter.  You could set up Neorouter on a laptop at the hospital and on a computer at home.  Once it's set up the Chromecast would connect to the laptops wifi which would put it on the same network as the home Neorouter.

I've never tried it but it should work.